# Excel Mathematical tool automation

Tags: excel, vba

I have designed an excel mathematical tool for automotive application. The tool is fed with 5 inputs (1 data set) and it returns 4 outputs. The problem is that i have 20000 data sets (each data set having 5 inputs) and i need to calculate the outputs (4 outputs for each data set) for 20000 data sets. It would be really grateful if u guys can try helping me out. I would really appreciate if someone could explain me step by step wat has to be done.
Or in other words , i have 2 excel workbooks. One is the mathematical tool and another is the data sheet which has the input datas of 20000 sets.  I would like the mathematical tool to call for input datas from the data sheet and return the calculated values back to the same data sheets as output.

Answer (score 0):

With the picture of your last comment I have now a TOOL.xlsm like this:

[image]

and a DATA.xlsx like this:

[image]

Note the .xlsm for TOOL.xlsm because there have to be macros in it.

Then I have a Module in TOOL.xlsm with the following macro:

```
Sub calculateInputRange()
 Dim oWBTOOL As Workbook, oWBDATA As Workbook
 Set oWBTOOL = ThisWorkbook
 Set oWBDATA = Workbooks("DATA.xlsx")
 'DATA.xlsx has to be open. TODO:Error handling if not

 oWBDATA.Activate
 Dim oInputRange As Range, oOutputStartRange As Range
 On Error Resume Next
 Set oInputRange = Application.InputBox("Select range with INPUT values", Type:=8)
 Set oOutputStartRange = Application.InputBox("Select start range for Output values", Type:=8)
 On Error GoTo 0
 If oInputRange Is Nothing Or oOutputStartRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

 Dim oRow As Range
 Dim i As Long
 For Each oRow In oInputRange.Rows
  oWBTOOL.Worksheets("INPUT|OUTPUT").Range("C3:C6").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(oRow.Value)
  Calculate
  oOutputStartRange.Offset(i, 0).Value = oWBTOOL.Worksheets("INPUT|OUTPUT").Range("F3").Value
  oOutputStartRange.Offset(i, 1).Value = oWBTOOL.Worksheets("INPUT|OUTPUT").Range("F4").Value
  i = i + 1
 Next
End Sub
```

Both Workbooks TOOL.xlsm and DATA.xlsx have to be open.

Now you can run the macro. It will ask first for the range with INPUT values. Select all input values, B4:E20 for example. Then it will ask for the start range for OUTPUT values. Select one cell, H4 for example.

The macro takes row by row from the selected input values and put these values in `oWBTOOL.Worksheets("INPUT|OUTPUT").Range("C3:C6").Value`. Then it calculates and takes the result values from `oWBTOOL.Worksheets("INPUT|OUTPUT").Range("F3").Value` and `...Range("F4").Value` into the DATA.xlsx.

This is what you describe as requirement. But it is not what I would call the best solution. If the input values in DATA.xlsx change, the result values will not change automatically.  You have to run the macro selecting the changed input values and the start cell for the output values.

Consider to do the calculations you seems to do within the sheet "calculator" directly in VBA. Then you could have a User Defined Function (UDF) in TOOL.xlsm like this:

```
Public Function getResultsFromMyTool(inputs As Range) As Variant
 'inputs is a range
 Dim arr_inputs As Variant
 arr_inputs = inputs.Value
 'now arr_inputs is an array

 'get the single inputs from the array
 'we get only the case, that inputs was a range of cells in a row
 Dim i1 As Double, i2 As Double, i3 As Double, i4 As Double, i5 As Double
 i1 = arr_inputs(1, 1)
 i2 = arr_inputs(1, 2)
 i3 = arr_inputs(1, 3)
 i4 = arr_inputs(1, 4)

 'simply do here what your tool does with the inputs in sheet "calculator"
 Dim arr_outputs(0 To 3) As Double
 arr_outputs(0) = i1 + i3 / i4 - i2
 arr_outputs(1) = i2 * i3 / i2 + i4

 'return the output array
 getResultsFromMyTool = arr_outputs
End Function
```

And in DATA.xlsx H4:I4 you call simply:

`{=TOOL.xlsm!getResultsFromMyTool(B4:E4)}`

and fill this downwards as needed.

The results of this UDF will be updated every time the sheets calculation runs, just like other Excel formulas. This would be better in my opinion.

Comment: @ Alex Richter , actually in the above image ,u have done the calculation on the same sheet. In my case the calculation is to be done by a different excel  file (TOOL). The data sheet is a different excel sheet ( same as Ur uploaded pic) which should provide data to the tool excel sheet, the tool excel sheet should do the calculation and return the outputs to the data excel sheet( as shown in your pic). So how can it be achieved?

Comment: @alex , it would be really helpful if i can share my file with you.

Comment: The UDF is within a Module in the TOOL Workbook and then shall be called from the Data Workbook to return the 4 results there? Then you should create an AddIn from the TOOL Workbook. While the TOOL workbook is open you could call the UDF as `{=TOOLWBsName.xlsm!getResultsFromMyTool(A3:E3)}` without creating an AddIn.

Comment: @ alex, i am getting confused over here, please go through the image http://i.imgur.com/ETC83wc.jpg    .  I am new to vba, it would be really helpful if you can help me out. Also i have changed the no of inputs to 4 and outputs to 2.